# Figure out monitor resolution and window sizing

Tags: resolution

I am having some trouble figuring out monitor resolution and window sizing in terms of physical size on the screen.

Here's my current setup:
19" monitor
1280 x 958 resolution
I have a program that I like to run with a window of 1100 x 900 pixels

My current setup provides a physical size on the screen that is easy to read from multiple distances and I want to maintain that. I cannot adjust any font or graphic settings in the program, only window dimensions.

I am considering getting a 27" widescreen monitor at 2560 x 1440. Would I be able to fit **TWO** 1100 x 900 windows on this monitor and (generally) keep the same physical size for readability on this monitor?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is pixel density. A monitor with higher resolution on the same size screen will typically have smaller text and graphics. In this case you are changing the screen size and resolution at the same time, so you may want to calculate Pixels Per Inch (PPI). I've used this site to do this for you:

http://pixeldensitycalculator.com/

Original monitor - 19" 1280 x 958
PPI: 84.15

New monitor - 27" 2560 x 1440
PPI: 108.79

The new monitor has about 29% higher pixel density, which would correlate to it typically being that much smaller physically. You would be able to fit two 1100 x 900 windows side by side on this monitor.

If this would result in text that is too small then there may be other factors in play that may affect your experience.

- You may be able to lower the resolution of the new monitor to provide larger text/graphics experience. This depends on the features of the monitor.
- Depending on the operating system, the text may be able to be scaled at higher resolutions, or may automatically scale.
- You can move the screen closer to your face (probably not ideal)